# Table constraint, number of row taken by a fk key

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Is it posible to add a table constraint, to prevent an insert if there are already 3 row of the same `fk key`

`My table: ProjectTitles (id(pk), project_id(fk), title_id(fk))`

Check if project_id has less then 3 rows, if true `insert` if not show error

Comment: So allow a maximum of 3 rows with same `project_id` value for every project_id value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to add a column (say `project_title_no`) that allows only 3 possible values and a unique constraint on `(project_id, project_title_no`):

```
ALTER TABLE ProjectTitles
  ADD COLUMN project_title_no smallint not null ;

ALTER TABLE ProjectTitles
  ADD CHECK (project_title_no IN (1,2,3)) ;

ALTER TABLE ProjectTitles
  ADD UNIQUE (project_id, project_title_no) ;
```

One drawback is that this column is not automatically filled and you have to supply the value, either in your application or by creating suitable insert/update procedures (that check first if for example, for some project there are rows with title_no 1 and 3, and fill the missing 2).

It requires 2 extra bytes* which seems a lot for only 3 values but it's easily modifiable (the requirements change to 10 titles per project? Easy, just change the `CHECK` constraint.)

There are no table locking required though or race conditions that come with a trigger solution.

Comment: elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with a trigger, you'll find a good answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743439/how-to-write-a-constraint-concerning-a-max-number-of-rows-in-postgresql